# Mesh Ventilation Grill?

Tags: modeling

How do you proerply model a MESH TYPE VENTILATION GRILL for a PC? In the photo, this diamond shape object is actually a MESH GRILL from COOLERMASTER MASTERBOX K500L chassis.

I've tried using a PNG file I created in illustration as texture with alpha but it just doesn't look right to me. (no BUMPS, and SHDAOWS)

I'm thinking of manually doing BOOLEAN DIFFERENCE to the surface but I know that's just stupid.

Anybody else have done this before?

[image]

Comment: Stay away from booleans... There is nothing wrong using an image and transparency (it is the most efficient way to keep things low poly). You can add other images or patterns to create a bump map and add it to the existing. The shadows depend on the lighting.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/50667#50667

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a hexagonal grill?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill)

Comment: "*Anybody else have done this before?*"  Yes, many times, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-create-a-circular-shaped-grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39460/how-can-a-evenly-spaced-grid-with-a-circular-boundary-be-modeled and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109185/texture-with-a-grid-of-points-with-python

Comment: "Stay away from booleans" → Why? It's completely fine to use booleans, they are powerful tools among others. They might not be the best way to go in this particular case, but surely not a "no go".  "Only a Sith deals in absolutes".

Comment: Booleans are well known for producing bad topology, causing artifacts and failing often for many common cases. Searching this site should show you how often. Modelling it with proper topology from the start will teach you valuable skills and avoid certain grief down the road

Comment: @L0Lock Booleans will create a lots of ngons, triangles and irregular or messy topology, creating more problems down the line. There is a place and a time for booleans, but for the most part is a lazy solution for things that are better solved with proper modeling or texturing. In this case a very efficient solution has already been found by the person posting the question, it just need some enhancing.

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87460/1853

Comment: thank you for the response guys. appreciate it!!